# How to clear memory contents in C?

Tags: c

I'm defining  a char pointer in this manner.

```
char *s=(char *)malloc(10);
```

After I fill in all possible values that can fit here, I want to clear whatever I wrote to s and without using malloc again want to write in s? How can I do this?

I need to update the contents but if in the last iteration not all values are updated, then I'll be processing over old values which I do not want to do.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "clear".

Comment: why bother with cleaning the value if you want to update the contents of `s` anyway?

Comment: `sizeof(2*5)` looks funny... Try also `sizeof(2/0)`

Comment: @AlexFarber that would give you a block of infinite size.

Comment: @WouterH A dream comes true! You deserve a Nobel prize ;)

Comment: @WouterH: and `sizeof(-1000)` would give you a negative-sized array: quite useful if you are out of memory!

Comment: [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset)?

Comment: free(s) will free the memory allocated to pointer s.

Comment: @AlexFarber ah yes, it's `sizeof(int)`

Comment: If you want to set the memory zone to zero, you can use [calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc). By the way, personally, when I run out of memory, I prefer to call Chuck Norris. The RAM chips get so scared that they split, which gives me double the memory. Well, that's what Chuck Norris told me anyway after I gave him my soul.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be careful!

`malloc(sizeof(2*5))` is the same as `malloc(sizeof(int))` and allocates just 4 bytes on a 32 bit system. If you want to allocate 10 bytes use `malloc(2 * 5)`.

---

You can clear the memory allocated by `malloc()` with `memset(s, 0, 10)` or `memset(s, 0, sizeof(int))`, just in case this was really what you intended.

See [man memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

---

Another way to clear the memory is using [`calloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of malloc. This allocates the memory as malloc does, but sets the memory to zero as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can "clear" memory by using `memset`, and setting all the bytes in the memory block to `0`.  So for instance:

```
#define MEMORY_BLOCK 10

//allocate memory
unsigned char* s = malloc(MEMORY_BLOCK);

//... do stuff

//clear memory
memset(s, 0, MEMORY_BLOCK);
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations:

- You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.
- Your `malloc()` argument looks wrong; note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. It will evaluate to the size of the type of its argument: 2 * 5 has type `int`, so the value will probably be 4. Note that this is the same for all integer expressions: `sizeof 1` is the same as `sizeof 100000000`.

Your question is very unclear, it's not easy to understand why you feel you have to "clear" the string area. Memory is memory, it will hold what you last wrote to it, there's no need to "clear" it between writes. In fact, a "clear" is just a write of some specific value.